# threshold algorithm

Tags: histogram, image-segmentation

Does anyone know of any reference or sample code of the "Minimum Error Thresholding" algorithm?  Java has a method called "getMinErrorThreshold" in the Histogram class and I want to implement this algorithm in C.

Thank you

Alessandro Ferrucci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just look at the java source?

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules/Java-Advanced-Imaging/javax/media/jai/Histogram.java.htm

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should have looked harder for the source code ;)